# Getting active value in std::visit without knowing which value is active

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

I want to get the active value in a std::variant without knowing which one is active. I thought i could write a template visitor and use std::visit but it doesn't work.

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Visit_configuration {
    template<typename Data_type>
    Data_type operator()(Data_type& t) const
    {
        return t;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, std::string> v;
    v = "hello";

    std::cout << std::visit(Visit_configuration(), v);   // expect "hello"
    std::cin.get();
}
```

MSVC doesn't compile and throws:

> error C2338: visit() requires the result of all potential invocations
>   to have the same type and value category (N4741 23.7.7
>   [variant.visit]/2).
>
> note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int
>   std::visit&,0>(_Callable
>   &&,std::variant &)' being compiled

So how to fix this?

edit: I want to use the obtained value maybe also for other so putting cout in the template isn't what im looking for.

Comment: While you and I can see that `v` will always contain a `std::string`, and a good static analysis tool will could also make that determination, it's beyond what a compiler is required to be able to deduce. Notably, `v` isn't `constexpr` and the compiler doesn't understand what `v` contains at compile time any more than if you depended on user input. So the return type of `std::visit` can't be determined.

Comment: You should have the visitor `operator()` output the value, rather than trying to return it from the visitor so the caller can output it.  For [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit): `std::visit([](auto&& arg){std::cout << arg;}, v);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ask yourself the question:
**What is the return type of `std::visit` if you don't know what part of the `variant` is active?**

That is the question that the compiler *must* answer. And the answer can't be "it depends" - you (as in, the compiler) must decide on **exactly one type** at compile-time. The `visit` call cannot possibly return different types at runtime.

If you want to work with different types "at runtime", you must be in a function templated on the type you want to work with. In other words, there **must** be different functions (or function template instantiations) to handle the "write an int to `cout`" and "write a string to `cout`" cases. You cannot do this in the same (non-templated) function.

The straightforward solution here is thus to put the `std::cout <<` into your templated visitor function - that's the point of visiting: Specifying what is supposed to happen in each case.

If you want to "use the obtained value maybe also for [some] other [purpose]", then that "other purpose" should also be part of the/a visitor. Only then can you have that "other purpose" handle the different cases at once (e.g. in a templated function). Otherwise you must decide at compile-time already which type shall be used - the compiler is not going to leave that choice open for later (run time).

Answer (score 4):

Return type of visitor function should be identical.

Create printer visitor instead:

```
struct PrinterVisitor {
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(const T& t) const
    {
        std::cout << t;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, std::string> v;
    v = "hello";

    std::visit(PrinterVisitor{}, v);   // expect "hello"
}
```

And in your case, you can even have lambda:

```
int main()
{
    std::variant<int, std::string> v;
    v = "hello";

    std::visit([](const auto& t){std::cout << t;}, v);   // expect "hello"
}
```

Comment: ok but what if i want to access the value for sth else than std::cout ? is there a way?

Comment: Please explain why/how this code is different than code in question.

Comment: @Sandro4912 Seems pretty straight forward to add a `std::ostream&` constructor to `PrinterVisitor`.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk: Return types of Visitor `operator()` should be identical, which is not the case for OP.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux So can it be different then `void`? Then `visit` returns the result?

Comment: Look at [`std::visit` doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)